# What is the name for this gigantic dropper or pipe that a person use to suck liquid out of a container?

Tags: hydrometer, measurements, beer-tools

I saw it in a video about hydrometer, and I can't find anywhere where to buy this gigantic dropper. what are its name and size? It seems about 250ml which is what I need. Thanks!

***The tube in the center, ignore the tube on two sides***

[image: The tube in the center, ignore the tube on two sides]

***that dropper in his hand! its not a dropper I just dont know its name at all!!***

[image: that dropper in his hand! its not a dropper I just dont know its name at all!!]

Comment: any recommendations about the material the wine thief is made of? when i brewed ginger bug, steel utensils was a big no-no so i am wondering about steel wine thief Vs plastic/glass. amazon seems to have all sorts but steel is the more common one by the looks of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a 'wine thief'. This should be readily available in any homebrew shop. Possibly in several sizes and qualities even.

Comment: I have a plastic wine thief after my first glass one shattered. The glass version i had was very thin glass so very fragile. A plastic one might be a little more robust to accidents...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a standard [cooking baster](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Fox-Run-11-Glass-Heat-Resistant-Baster-Rubber-Bulb-Kitchen-Cooking-Utensil-5678-/391575785461) to transfer liquid to your hydrometer vessel, but I'd recommend one that's made of glass and has a removable rubber bulb.